# Aggregate & arrange results in dataframe by two criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following excel sheet for an email campaign activity:

[image]

I want to track each email_title activity per customer and arrange it by date.

What I did so far with dataframe:

I filtered the customer_email list to get the unique number of emails:

```
Unique_emails = df.email.unique()
```

Then filtered the activity of each customer_email for the email_title & Status:

```
activity = ['delivered','opened']
for emails in Unique_emails:
    email_titles = df.loc[(df['customer_email'] == emails) & (df['status'].isin(activity)), ['email_title','date','status']]
```

Now, what I want is to aggregate the status of each email_title per customer.

The challenge is each customer has the same email_title, the first 3 rows show that email "elevate your skills in 15 minutes" was sent to email1@sample.com 2 times

first - delivered and opened (this is one activity) in 1/1/20
then second - delivered and not opened in 2/1/2020

Now I want to aggregate each email_title for each customer per date

[image]

How can I achieve this? I am not an expert in dataframes

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific scenario since `o` comes after `n` in the alphabet, you can simply take the `max` to see if `opened` or `not opened` should be the desired output per row, and it looks like that you need to use `last` for the `status` column, which looks for the last value for the group, which depends on sorting.

Input Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '1/1/2020', 1: '1/1/2020', 2: '2/1/2020'},
 'customer_email': {0: 'email1@sample.com',
  1: 'email1@sample.com',
  2: 'email1@sample.com'},
 'email_title': {0: 'Elevate your skills in 15 minutes',
  1: 'Elevate your skills in 15 minutes',
  2: 'Elevate your skills in 15 minutes'},
 'status': {0: 'opened', 1: 'delivered', 2: 'delivered'}})
df
```

---

Code:

```
(df.assign(**{'new status aggregrated per email title' : df['status'].replace('delivered', 'not opened')})
   .groupby(['date', 'customer_email', 'email_title'], as_index=False)
   .agg({'status' : 'last', 'new status aggregrated per email title' : 'max'}))
```

---

Output:

```
       date     customer_email                        email_title     status  \
0  1/1/2020  email1@sample.com  Elevate your skills in 15 minutes  delivered   
1  2/1/2020  email1@sample.com  Elevate your skills in 15 minutes  delivered   

  new status aggregrated per email title  
0                                 opened  
1                             not opened
```

Comment: Thank you David that is exactly what I want in action but I faced another issue what if the email sent in a specific date and then opened in another date - this won't aggregate this specific email_title. Any idea how can I do it? Thanks again

Comment: @Mtaly If you want to have the `latest status` per row, you can do something like this: `df['latest status'] = df.groupby(['customer_email', 'email_title'])['status'].transform('last')`. From there , you can tweak the above code to get to your endpoint.